# Errors in python script to remove NULL chars in a file

Tags: bash, python-2.7

Newbie question: I want to write a python script which removes all the NULL characters in a file and count how many non-NULL characters left.

### Equivalent Linux command line:

```
# Linux-machine:$ tr -dc [:print:] < raw-test.txt | wc -c
# Linux-machine:$ more -f raw-test.txt
abcdefghij^@^@^@^@^@^@.....
```

raw-test.txt file has 10 non-NULL characters in it (abcdefghij).

Python code:

---

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["tr", "-d", "-c", "[:print:]", "<", "raw-test.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print output
```

### Errors:

```
# Linux-machine:$ python raw-test-trim.py
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2

# Linux-machine:$
```

Please help me see my errors.

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO redirections like `< infile`, `> outfile` are syntax from shell. OS doesn't recognize it.

With subprocess, you should either set `shell=True` or use python open() to redirect.

```python
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('tr -d -c [:print:] < raw-test.txt', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print output

with open('raw-test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["tr", "-d", "-c", "[:print:]"], stdin=f, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
print output
```